# Running Grails functional tests in Grails 3

Tags: grails, functional-testing, grails3, web-api-testing

This seems to be a very basic functionality that is provided by Grails but I am not able to get to work. I am trying to add some API tests for my application using the documentation provided [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#functionalTesting).

After adding the test and running `grails test-app -integration` I don't see tests getting executed. Below is the output of the command.

```
➜  myProj git:(func-test) ✗ grails test-app -integration

> Configure project :
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date
| Tests PASSED
```

I don't see any tests getting executed.

Below is my test which I am expecting to fail.

```
package myApp

import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*

import spock.lang.*
import geb.spock.*

/**
 * See http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/ for more instructions
 */
@Integration
@Rollback
class UsersSpec extends GebSpec {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "visit homepage"() {
        when:"The home page is visited"
            go '/'

        then:"The title is correct"
            title == "Welcome to My Application"
    }
}
```

I have also tried running the test class directly using the following commands:

```
grails test-app myApp.UsersSpec
grails test-app -integration myApp.UsersSpec
grails test-app -functional
grails test-app -functional myApp.UsersSpec
```

But none of them seems to be executing the required test.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tests are defined under `src/integration-test/groovy/` and you haven't done anything unusual with respect to reconfiguring your test source folders then you can run them several ways.  I suggest using Gradle:

```
./gradlew integrationTest
```

(leave the `./` off if you are on Windows)